# Whenever I export the report from crystal then it add "i" automatically in text objects

Tags: crystal-reports

While Export report as a PDF then this problem occurs.

[image: image1]

Original report like below image.

[image: image2]

Comment: Whats happen when you present report into preview mode?

Comment: in preview mode it shows right . But when i export that report as a pdf then in that pdf it automatically add "i" after all "t" .

Comment: can you export report into doc format? maybe its a problem with pdf conversion

Comment: I want in only pdf . Thats it

Comment: Of course, but if you try to export report in other format you can see if the problem repeat.